# MySQL Running Balance View Error

Tags: mysql

Hello I am trying to create a view in MySQL but I am getting syntax error # 1064 i.e

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for > the right syntax to use near 'SET @csum := 0; at line 3

Here how can I fix this variable issue any solution or alternate method to calculate running balance with ease

Here is my code

```
SET @csum := 0;
SELECT
tblleasesalesschedule_details.LeaseSaleID,
tblleasesalesschedule_details.ScheduleSr,
tblleasesalesschedule_details.InstallmentName,
tblleasesalesschedule_details.InstallmentSr,
tblleasesalesschedule_details.ScheduleDate,
tblleasesalesschedule_details.Amount,
IFNULL(tblleasesalespayment.Amount, 0) AS AmountPaid,
(coalesce(tblleasesalesschedule_details.Amount, 0) - coalesce(tblleasesalespayment.Amount, 0)) As BalanceAmount,
(@csum := @csum + (coalesce(tblleasesalesschedule_details.Amount, 0) - coalesce(tblleasesalespayment.Amount, 0))) as RunningBalance,
tblleasesalespayment.PaymentDate
FROM
tblleasesalespayment
RIGHT JOIN tblleasesalesschedule_details ON tblleasesalesschedule_details.InstallmentSr = tblleasesalespayment.InstallmentSr
WHERE
tblleasesalesschedule_details.PayDate < NOW();
```

Comment: you are creating a view assing a var?   . show all the code please

Comment: yes but i am not sure in view we can assign variable or not this is the complete code i have, actually i am using navicat preimum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoi the use of var ins a view

A view definition is subject to the following restrictions:
(From Mysql Doc ) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html

> The SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery in the FROM clause.
>
> **The SELECT statement cannot refer to system variables or user-defined
>   variables.**
>
> Within a stored program, the SELECT statement cannot refer to program
>   parameters or local variables.
>
> The SELECT statement cannot refer to prepared statement parameters.
>
> Any table or view referred to in the definition must exist. If, after
>   the view has been created, a table or view that the definition refers
>   to is dropped, use of the view results in an error. To check a view
>   definition for problems of this kind, use the CHECK TABLE statement.
>
> The definition cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table, and you cannot
>   create a TEMPORARY view.
>
> You cannot associate a trigger with a view.
>
> Aliases for column names in the SELECT statement are checked against
>   the maximum column length of 64 characters (not the maximum alias
>   length of 256 characters).

if you need  the use of param take a look at function or procedure  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html